# Make images across Powerpoint presentation slides the same size, outline and position

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I've got a slide that's updated daily with images, and they're usually all added incorrectly by the other users. This means I have to resize, reposition and add an outline to meet the defined standard for these presentations.

I've found a macro which lets me resize all the images based on a selection

```
Sub Imagesize
Dim oshp As Shape
Dim oPic As Shape
Dim picH As Single
Dim picW As Single
Dim osld As Slide
If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = ppSelectionNone Then GoTo err
If ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count <> 1 Then GoTo err
Set oshp = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
For Each oPic In osld.Shapes

If oPic.Type = msoPicture Then
picW = oPic.Width
picH = oPic.Height
oPic.LockAspectRatio = True
oPic.Width = oshp.Width
oPic.Left = oPic.Left - (oshp.Width - picW) / 2
oPic.Top = oPic.Top - (oshp.Height - picH) / 2
End If

If oPic.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
If oPic.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType = msoPicture Then
picW = oPic.Width
picH = oPic.Height
oPic.LockAspectRatio = True
oPic.Width = oshp.Width
oPic.Left = oPic.Left - (oshp.Width - picW) / 2
oPic.Top = oPic.Top - (oshp.Height - picH) / 2
End If
End If

Next oPic
Next osld
Exit Sub
err:
MsgBox "Please select ONE shape and retry!", vbCritical
End Sub
```

It works perfectly, but does anyone know if anything can be added to this to make the images sit on a horizontal of 19cm and a vertical of 4cm?

Comment: Well, just answered my own question. It's two scripts but it'll do! Ignore me!

Comment: Rather than a comment saying you answered your own question it would be better if you posted an answer saying *how* you solved the problem.